# Django REST serialize output - group by foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have models like below.

Restaurant Model

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Name')
```

Menu Model

```
class Menu(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name='menu name')
```

Item Model

```
class Item(models.Model):

    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to get the menus for the shop id.

How can I group my results by menu for the restaurant id ?

**call GET /menus/restaurant_id**

Sample.

```
{
 name: menu name 1
 items: [ {item1}, {item2}]
},
{
 name: menu name 2
 items: [ {item1}, {item2}]
}
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i can find it's postgres specific aggregation function [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg)

You can use it like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

Item.objects.filter(restaurant_id=1).values('menu__name').annotate(items=ArrayAgg('name'))

# example output: 
# [
#     {
#         'menu__name': 'menu1',
#         'items': ['item1', 'item2']
#     },
#     {
#         'menu__name': 'menu2',
#         'items': ['item3', 'item4']
#     },
# ]
```

Such qs performs next raw sql query:

```
SELECT
  "appname_menu"."name",
  ARRAY_AGG("appname_item"."name") AS "items"
FROM "appname_item"
  INNER JOIN "appname_menu" ON ("appname_item"."menu_id" = "appname_menu"."id")
WHERE "appname_item"."restaurant_id" = 1
GROUP BY "appname_menu"."name"
```

Probably it can help you.